# When load "new questions", the ignore tags doesn't work

Tags: discussion, bug

First, I set the Ignored Tags as:

[image: Ignored Tags]

Then, when there's new questions and I'm trying to load them:

[image: load new questions]

And I'll see:

[image: loaded questions]

The problem is, I ignored these tags...

[image: tags which I ignored]

---

So if I want *remove* them, I need refresh the page. However I don't want always refresh the page if there's new questions. Is this a bug?